# Am I wrong in my judgment of questions that have to be closed?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I have been noticing recently that the questions I require for closure stay open, and I am the only one that thinks that these questions need to be closed.

In my opinion, these questions are clearly off topic. But since I'm the only one thinking it, I can admit I'm wrong so I need you to help me so I can fix my way of judging these questions.

Here are some examples:

- [Video: Snail climbing grass, queen in tin foil walking backwards](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/video-snail-climbing-grass-queen-in-tin-foil-walking-backwards) : ID question with no music detail
- [Identify EDM song, gang wearing hoods assaulting woman](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/identify-edm-song-gang-wearing-hoods-assaulting-woman) : ID question with no music detail
- [Did zain malik left islam or not?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7393/did-zain-malik-left-islam-or-not) and [Did Zayn Malik left Islam or not?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7392/did-zayn-malik-left-islam-or-not) : Two identical questions about religion
- [Record cartridge not working](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/4686/record-cartridge-not-working) : Technical assistance
- [How do I 'break it' to a musician that I don't like their music?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7037/how-do-i-break-it-to-a-musician-that-i-dont-like-their-music) : Interpersonal skills question

The community and the mods consider these questions on-topic so I'm the one in wrong, I understand. I just want to know why.

Comment: In the bigger picture this all seems to look more like a problem of *activity* than clear contradicting policies. I doubt those questions stay open because users genuinely thought they *ought* to stay open rather than simply noone really *noticing* (or caring, for that matter).

Comment: @MajorTom, since I asked for closure, people that have the close-vote rights should see them in the review list + the mods. It should be a dozen of people...

Comment: ...provied they check these queues *and* have a strong enough opinion on the matter. Both these things *might* be at odds, or they might not and it's really just a difference in policy viewpoints. However, *if* they are at odds, that's a point worth working on (maybe even more so than the actual policies).

Answer (score 4):

We as a site need to have more discussions on what is on and off topic and we need people with close privileges to go through the queues. I agree with all you assessments so I have closed them, but we should have bigger discussions  about each topic especially the identification questions.

I've in the past tried to be quicker with going through the queues, but met some resistance so I'm trying to leave a lot of this up to the community. The problem is that we've leaned on quantity over quality so we've catered to a lot of borderline content that should be closed.

Comment: So what do we need to do now?

Comment: @Bebs focus on what we can and discuss issues as a community.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but how? When do we start?