# The [identify*]-question question: Time for a trial separation?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, identification-questions

---

<sub>**Full dislosure:** It was [an identify question of my own](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/10756/9288) that initially turned me onto this site.</sub>

---

## TL;DR

- Music Fans SE should engage in a **time-limited trial run** of restricting or eliminating "identify" questions.

There are three sections to this post: (1) Two proposals; (2) Justification; (3) Stats.

---

## Two proposals regarding "[identify*]" questions

#### Proposal #1:

Treat "identify" questions as off-topic for **a one-year trial period** to observe the effect on overall participation.

**...or...**

#### Proposal #2

Restrict, for a **one-year trial period** the "identify" questions that are on-topic. For example:

1. Require that any posted video be on a publicly accessible site (e.g., not a personal cloud-share site; not a site requiring fees). (Also in the interest of security. I have no interest in downloading unknown files from random sites.)
2. Require that the above site track views, and that the submitted video have a minimum such number (e.g., 10,000). This will at least suggest some future usefulness.

## Justification

"Identify" questions have been a point of discussion, contention, and, for some, irritation since the inception of Music Fans. For example:

- [“Identify this song / genre / artist” - on topic?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/identify-this-song-genre-artist-on-topic) (Feb 2015)
- [Burn the identify-this-track tag?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218/burn-the-identify-this-track-tag) (May 2015)
- [On-topic & Off-topic](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231/on-topic-off-topic) (June 2015)
- [Why identify-this-* tag hasn't been banned?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327/why-identify-this-tag-hasnt-been-banned) (Dec 2016)
- [Answered question with dead link](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324/answered-question-with-dead-link) (Dec 2016)
- [No effort, no research, no use to future visitors](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/no-effort-no-research-no-use-to-future-visitors) (Feb 2017)
- [Am I wrong in my judgment of questions that have to be closed?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/448/am-i-wrong-in-my-judgment-of-questions-that-have-to-be-closed) (Nov 2018)
- The question you're currently reading (Oct 2020)
- [Should we be strict with the identification tags?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/730/9288) (Oct 2021)

As shown in the stats below, "identify" questions are

1. **Pushing out other questions**;
2. **Producing less engagement and less impact**;
3. **Of lower quality**.

One concern has been that limiting or removing "identify" questions will reduce site growth. However, as measured by number of questions asked, growth is stagnant even with them (see Stats, below). Evidence suggests "identify" questions are actually suppressing growth.

As a personal matter, I find "identify"-type questions to be a drag most of the time. They often take a substantial amount of research to answer and are generally of limited long-term or popular value. For me, the "identify" questions have become a significant disincentive and have substantially reduced my participation.

I advocate strongly for a trial run of either restricting or removing them.

## Stats

1. In Music Fans's first year (Feb - Dec 2015) the ratio of "other" questions to "identify" questions was better than 4:1. However, since 2016, the number of "identify" questions has been holding steady at roughly double, while the number of "other" questions has dropped by more than 50%.

```
TABLE 1: Questions by year
____________________________________

          [Identify*]
      ____________________
Year   Is  (%)     Not (%)     Total
____________________________________
2021*  217 (62%)   135 (38%)   352
2020   189 (48%)   203 (52%)   392
2019   236 (59%)   165 (41%)   401
2018   206 (53%)   183 (47%)   389
2017   235 (50%)   231 (50%)   466
2016   231 (44%)   294 (56%)   525
2015** 108 (19%)   472 (81%)   580
_________________________________
*as of Nov. 30, 2021
**first site question asked 2/2015
```

2. "Identify" questions are significantly less engaging and less impactful than other questions.

```
TABLE 2: Question impact/popularity*
____________________________________________________
                 Averages
          ______________________
Q-type    Score  Views  Favorite  >1 answers/total Q 
____________________________________________________
identify  1       715   0         263/1445 = 18.2%
other     4      2364   1         555/1703 = 32.6%
____________________________________________________
*Based on data from SEDE. Queries are below.
```

3. "Identify" questions are of lower quality than other questions.

```
TABLE 3: Percentages of closed questions versus total
_____________________________________________________

Tag        Closed/Total  %
_____________________________
Identify*  50/1463       3.4%
Other      93/4292       2.7%
```

---

```
Queries used for Table 2.

SELECT AVG(ViewCount) FROM Posts WHERE Tags LIKE '%identify%'  
SELECT AVG(ViewCount) FROM Posts WHERE Tags NOT LIKE '%identify%'  

SELECT AVG(Score) FROM Posts WHERE Tags LIKE '%identify%'
SELECT AVG(Score) FROM Posts WHERE Tags NOT LIKE '%identify%'

SELECT AVG(FavoriteCount) FROM Posts WHERE Tags LIKE '%identify%'
SELECT AVG(FavoriteCount) FROM Posts WHERE Tags NOT LIKE '%identify%'

SELECT COUNT(AnswerCount) FROM Posts WHERE Tags LIKE '%identify%' AND AnswerCount > 1
SELECT COUNT(AnswerCount) FROM Posts WHERE Tags NOT LIKE '%identify%' AND AnswerCount > 1
```

Comment: I'll see if I can link other questions important to the track of identification questions on this site over the next few days. They were supposed to be trial only and it never really seemed successful in my opinion, but was near impossible to roll back once it started. I'll also point out another problem with identification questions on this site in your question which is the one answer you got is incorrect, but still upvoted. The questions are set up so only the OP can validate the question, but anyone can upvote the answer making it have issues on a Q&A site.

Comment: This question is tangentially related: https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/how-to-improve-quality/423#423 . This question was very important for getting ID questions from off topic to on topic: [Should the site's scope be expanded to increase user engagement?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/should-the-sites-scope-be-expanded-to-increase-user-engagement).

Comment: About hosting services: [Should we restrict hosting services we allow for ID questions?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/should-we-restrict-hosting-services-we-allow-for-id-questions)

Comment: Much of your argument for making such questions off-topic here is based on the premise that even the mere *presence* of such questions on this site harms it. Any user who feels this could just use SE's "Ignore tag" feature on this or any other tag.

Comment: @RosieF That's a fair read, but I'm also saying that they aren't helping -- usage is going down even with them, both in terms of total user engagement and per-question engagement. So I propose a time-limited trial run without them to see if that has a positive effect on overall site usage.

Comment: I beg of you to please vote against such action. Especially point number 1

Comment: @cmp Just to clarify, are your referring to "proposal #1", the first item in the stats section, or something else?

Comment: @Aaron My apologies, yes. It can’t be abandoned altogether. I did see someone bitterly regret it’s removal on the Movies Stack Exchange site. Many said “It was the reason I first engaged with the site and continue to engage with it”. A large audience will be missed and dismissed, not to mention the considerable amount [closed] dead questions that will be inevitable.

Comment: The reasoning behind ID questions being removed from M&TV was the sheer number of lazy questions. That some well-researched questions may have been lost, as the baby with the bathwater, I think has seen the overall question quality on there go up. I'm still very much engaged there, whereas here I poke my head in once a month if I'm bored. The ID questions imo are generally zero value. Most of the current front page is either 'name this tune' or 'what genre is this?' both of which are equally pointless.

Comment: Is there any way to tell how many ID question askers are likely to return & fully engage with the site longer term, vs fly-by askers?

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh but you see they provide much value to the user. That long awaited song they never quite managed to remember. The same with the movies. The relief that you finally know the movie. You’re lazy questions example applies to all questions. You have to provide as much help as possible. Above all, you have to prove that you have tired your absolute hardest to establish the answer for yourself. On the other hand, if they were now considered off-topic (goodness forbid) at least your question would be top of the list for some time!

Comment: The idea of stack exchange as a whole is not to provide value to a single user, but to become a permanent searchable resource for many users. If a question is unsearchable, ie "what's this song? link provided." then it is of literally no value to anyone at all except the asker. Many SE sites have that as a close reason.

Comment: @Tetsujin If we are prepared to see this particular network even less popular than it is already, we are going the right way about it. I have to say it’s very ironic that the person writing this post was first initially engaged to this site by an identify question. Anyway, Reddit exists and will always dominate this platform.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not here to emulate Reddit, or any forum-style site. It is a searchable resource for many users. I see no irony in the question - though I do in the answer to the OP's initial post, which though not the right answer was the only one… & it was mine ;) The question itself was at least a good attempt to provide full information & may possibly be googlable. It didn't just say "what's the song in this video?" which has absolutely zero value as a searchable resource.

Comment: @Tetsujin That’s what I am saying to you. If it’s a well written question, with effort having been constructed, let this beautiful community answer it. If it’s poor, terribly composed, the let it be deleted. Without hesitation. We cannot abandon these style questions when they are so very popular.

Comment: @cmp It sounds like you might be open to setting some tighter criteria for what qualifies as a "good" identify question. I'd be interested in your thoughts on how the criteria could be narrowed to better catch the valuable questions and better filter the "lazy" ones or the ones meant to drive traffic to a YouTube channel, etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin Your upvote (sounds like you agree with me) would be very much appreciated. With a current score of 4, it seems likely nothing will happen even if a solution is agreed on.

Comment: One of your example questions was mine - we've travelled this road before ;) It's always gained some traction, but never arrived at any official conclusion.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's why I'm resorting to drumming up votes. There's seeming support from at least one mod (Dom), and if some momentum could be gathered, perhaps this is the time something can happen. Inertia is also why I've limited my proposals to "trial runs". I'm still holding out hope there will be some discussion of counterproposals or changes/refinements to the options I've suggested.

Comment: @Aaron You simply have to have tried to answer the question on your own. You have to prove that you have tried either google.com or google.co.uk in order to have come up with an answer. If you have resorted to all research, feel free to ask on here. Like I have said in the comments, if you’re prepared for this network to be even more unpopular than it is already, go ahead and disable these types of questions altogether. Bottom line, do your research first. If no solid answer is found, ask away.

Comment: I read through this thread very quickly, and now I can't help but wonder whether or not my identify question (which you answered back then) is one of the reasons why this type of question is badly viewed. I must admit, Stack Exchange is about the only place I know to ask that kind of question, because I know there are knowledgeable people from whom I can learn. Still, I think the only reason why I feel inclined to keeping that kind of question is because I mostly spend my time on the Science Fiction & Fantasy site. Over there, I have a lot of fun reading ID questions =>

Comment: => I guess that's just because I just love trivia. Sometimes, I found myself spending the entire day reading plot summary on Wikipedia, to the point that I happened to remember a movie as if I had watched it, when I only read about it. Still, I think that kind of "happy reading" isn't applicable here, because it's just a music sample (if there is a sample, rather than a readable story with a narrative and such.

Comment: @Clockwork You've hit on what I see as a major downside of "identify" questions. Unlike a book summary, the questions here rarely contain (specific) enough information, and they tend to rely on links that are apt to go bad eventually. Clearly there are enough people who post/read/answer these questions that they've been kept on the site, but for me personally it's a major disinsentive. I mostly just visit now to help manage the review queues and not much else.

Comment: Well, that "major downside" point is convincing enough, I upvoted, even though I liked that you were able to help me identify a music sample.

Comment: "help me identify" are the worst questions. They are super low quality, other stack exchange sites BSN then for this reason. They offer no value to anyone else other than the original poster and the suck all of the oxygen out of the site for other questions. Kill them, kill them now.

Comment: Low value, poor quality growth is worse than slow growth.

Comment: It may also be worth considering how other sites on the Stack Exchange network have handled "identification"-type questions. Some sites have disallowed them entirely, some others largely allow them without any special rules, and some other sites allow identification questions if they meet certain criteria or include certain details.

Comment: (Also: In searching for examples, I came across FAQs on other sites' metas (e.g. Anime & Manga, Movies & TV) that direct users to this site for certain kinds of identification questions, so those posts may also need to be updated if this site's policy changes.)

Comment: @V2Blast I'd love to disallow them completely, but when most of your questions are them at this point, it's rather hard. We really should have just never allowed them.

Comment: @Dom I don't think that is possible (to never allow them to begin with), because there will always be some kind of incentive to just try them out despite experiences with them on other sites. Maybe they just won't be *that* bad? But ultimately...they *will*, but try to tell that to an enthusiastic new beta userbase. It's like Robert put it in an answer I often kept returning to with sad feelings: *"This site is going to have identify-this-movie questions. It's almost a rite of passage… and then you'll regret it"*. Though, it's indeed a lot harder to kick them out once they've taken the site.

Comment: We tried stricter rules for ID questions on M&TV: people ignored them, and got angry when these rules were pointed out. ID questions are often so lazy that people *don't even use the identify tag* (e.g. this site's current frontpage where I just had to add the tag to half a dozen questions). Saying that people can filter out ID questions if they find them annoying is pointless when the askers don't properly tag them. Wanna know what is really annoying? Cleaning up someone else's mess.

Answer (score 10):

My reflex is to say yes, goodness yes, these questions tend to be such poor quality they is just noise.

However, on reflection, I think there should be some allowed. I think the criteria should be you ***must*** include one of the following (or similar)...

- an actual audio source for the piece of music (for example a youtube video) **including a time code** (unless it is throughout)
- the movie or tv show which you heard it in **with timecode** or just **it is the theme song, or the closing credits etc.**
- an actual image of the sheet music, but not something the OP has produced, an actual source

So this makes the following unacceptable...

- Half remembered lyrics (**something about a lover who leaves early in the morning?**)
- vague thematic descriptions (**a syth song with dark themes about nuclear war?**)
- descriptions of music videos (**children wearing dolls masks?**)
- OP produced recordings of melody or chords
- OP produced partial score, chord progressions, or musical description (**a descending bass line with a reggae guitar and a woman singing**)

Answer (score 8):

FWIW, I have been active on Stack Overflow for years (11k rep) but was never aware of Music Fans. However, I got a song from the 80s stuck in my head but can't remember the band. After fruitless Googling (I remember some lyrics) I landed at Music Fans. I was just about to post a question about the song when I saw this meta post. Now, I'm not sure if I should.

My point is that since the site is still in beta, is it wise to ban a potentially large user base? Maybe you should wait and revisit this issue when the site is no longer in beta.

You may be wondering: if I do ask my question, what will my level of participation be after that? It's hard to say. But at least your numbers will have increased *slightly*.

Also, it has been mentioned that the Movies Stack Exchange has banned these types of questions. But over at Science Fiction and Fantasy, there are over 18k questions tagged ["story-identification"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) - so it seems to be very successfully handled there.

Comment: To your question, I'd say go ahead and post. They are currently on topic, and there are enthusiasts who enjoy these kinds of questions. To the larger issue, I just want to reiterate that my OP doesn't suggest an outright ban. My proposals are 1) a time-limited trial run of a ban and 2) restricting the criteria for these types of questions to be considered "on-topic".

Comment: ID questions "work" on S&F because in the end it is a fairly limited subject range, plus IIRC they're rather strict on the need to provide as much info as possible. M&TV is just waay too broad, plus the vast majority of questions were low-quality. And its askers were so fly-by-night you'd be lucky for them to stick around to accept your answer. In fact these questions were so low-effort they often didn't include the "identify" tag (which is also happening here).

Answer (score 4):

This question was closed [Please help me identify this mandolin shaped guitar](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/11826/please-help-me-identify-this-mandolin-shaped-guitar) with a message stating it was "about identifying an artist, song, or genre of music" but that's not the case.  If asking to identify musical instruments is considered "off topic" the rule needs to be re-worded.  Or if the moderator misread the question, it should be re-opened.

Comment: Good point! All "identification" questions were made off-topic at the end of 2021 year (see [Identification Questions are now off-topic](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733/9288)), more than six months after you originally posted your question. (cont.)

Comment: When voting to close, the reason reads in part: "Use this close reason for question asking for help identifying an artist, song, genre, etc", but the "etc" isn't present in the guidance posted with the question after it's closed.

Comment: See [Identification question closed post guidance should match close vote reason](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/758/9288).

Comment: Meanwhile, the question would be welcome in chat. I would recommend the [Music Practice and Theory chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room) if only because it's currently more active that the [Music Fans chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21415/off-the-record).

Comment: It wasn't my question :) but I did participate in the discussion.  Thanks for clarifying that the summary is missing the "etc...".

Comment: Sloppy of me. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Similarly: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10129/what-kind-of-guitar-is-this

Comment: And this one https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/12968/what-type-of-guitar-is-playing-here which still shows the incorrect wording in the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

This site is dead, and the core responder base along with the mods killed it.

> “10 questions per day on average is a healthy beta, 5 questions or fewer per day needs some work. A healthy site generates lots of good content to make sure users keep coming back.”

Where is this quote from? Yeah, that’s right, it’s from area51. Today I took a glimpse in the heat of an argument about the hostility I got for an identify the *genre* question, and looked, the 5 days prior to that moment, the site had a total of 10 questions. 3 of which identify-type questions, all closed. Those people of getting a good answer, would come back. I would come back. Maybe only every 2 or 3 months. When my OST, lyrics Shamaz, humming or whistling a song to a song identifier algorithm each fails.

Think about it: When someone goes to such lengths, what quality of a music are they looking for? It’s the best of the best music of all genres people would come here, a preselected set. If it’s just good or mediocre, people won’t go to such lengths: It is interesting content. It is people passionate about music, understanding music. It’s the people of all SE’s coming here for this reasons with good music creating good content, and keep coming back every now and then.

Some will stick around to give the answers seeing its good music people come here with.

That exactly what area51 wants to see. The reason this site was created next to the other music site was for a place to have the identify questions. This place created by the rest of Stackexchange is it hijacked by a few and banning what this is for.

3 questioners would never come back here out of those 10 questions. They would, I would. Maybe only every quarter but definitely with some excellent music at the core of the question filling it with it value.

Talking about site health? The site is dead. And the leadership killed it.

There are some amazing proposals here, learn from it.

Identify genre is no more or less subjective than identifying the meaning of lyrics unlike who extremely widely a mod asserts in the comments. Unlike him, I studied aesthetics, not the nailing study one, but the one in a philosophy faculty of a prominent European university, and my initial focus was individual music philosophy.

No, the meaning of the lyrics is nothing less then an opinion based theory with preferably internal consistency.

Genre should be allowed. Identify with a linked recording should be allowed. You would surpass the 10 questions a day in two years.

It would take time for those you scared away to learn and return. But many SE users are only yet to learn about your existence. Try to make sure you make a good impression before Stackexchange puts the cross over this site. There could be value here.

Comment: For someone who's never coming back to this dead site, you certainly seem to be spending more time here than anyone else and singlehandedly keeping it alive. Kudos. The next step would be to come up with a post that is both on topic and interesting to others on the site. Good luck.

Comment: If we want to talk about what to talk about instead of stuff music, than I guess you don’t need to change because someone people may show up here, and tell you the same once in a blue moon.

Comment: You didn't get any hostility, your question was simply closed as being off-topic with no comment & only a single downvote. Identification questions have been made off-topic on many SE sites over the last couple of years. Across the various sites this was done, it was determined that [identify] tag users are less likely to return to the site than others, & only some even come back to mark an answer. The questions themselves are also more likely to be unsearchable by others & are often linked to an external site, leading to link-rot. They do not become a long-term useful resource.

Comment: Identify tag’s, for e.g., on mechanics.SE allowing auto identification works no issue, despite there rarely is a situation when the same person may need this multiple times in their life. Music identification is a common and everyday experience of people. When their tech fails, they would come here. Car identification is completely unsearchable. Genre identification absolutely isn’t. Because the requisite is the music to be genre’d. You give an artist and a title, and get a genre back. May be of less value than a song ID, but definitely searchable. Answer accepting? Allow ‘em only for a bounty