# Should we be strict with the identification tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, flagging, close-reasons

We presently have several `identify-this-x` tags:

[image: Screenshot of the available tags.]

I've noticed that some posts with this tag tend to be off of memory alone ([here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/12282/heavy-metal-album-man-with-black-makeup-tangled-in-barbed-wire-on-cover), [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/12260/whats-the-artist-who-actually-gets-beat-up-in-one-of-his-music-videos), and [here](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/12200/looking-for-the-name-of-a-piece-of-film-music-choir-alternating-between-right-a) are a few). While these posts can be interesting, and fun to research, they are rather vague and can be *very* hard to identify (sometimes impossible).

What should we do with posts like these? Should we flag/close them as "needs more details", or do we consider them off-topic due to the fact that the lack of information is unlikely to be remedied?

Comment: See also: [The [identify*]-question question: Time to say good-bye?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/715/9288).

Comment: IMO, a definite "yes". I currently and routinely vote to close as both "needs more details" and for the reasons listed in the site-specific close options.

Comment: The question Aaron linked seems in favour of outlawing the questions altogether. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identification Questions are now off-topic. Here's our next steps](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/733/identification-questions-are-now-off-topic-heres-our-next-steps)