# off-topic or overzealous moderation?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, identification-questions

I posted an ID question yesterday for a piece of classical music. I included a recording of me playing the theme on an electronic instrument. My question was flagged as off topic, closed and removed.

Turns out it was from Grieg's Peer Gynt. Someone in the Classical Music Subreddit IDed it in an hour.

Is this forum community moderated? If so, why the flag? Who flagged it?

Comment: The close reason & further comment below your question explained why. ID questions are off-topic, as of quite recently so not all the documentation is up to date on it yet. This isn't a forum, but it is moderated. A moderator closed your question. This question is also off-topic & should have been asked in Meta. Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help) to familiarise yourself with how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: Please take the time? Really? I did. 

This is from https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Please note that ID questions (What is the name of this song/band/etc?) are currently considered on-topic, provided that the question contains sufficient detail to make the identification possible. A link to an actual recording is best, but if one is not available, clear, specific and plentiful details including language, genre, style, lyrics, etc may be enough.

Comment: As @Tetsujin mentioned, all identification questions are off-topic as of Dec. 15, 2021. The change is recent enough that not all documentation has been updated, so your question happened to be asked during an ambiguous time where, unfortunately, your due diligence was frustrated. Please see [Identification Questions are now off-topic. Here's our next steps](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/733/9288) and linked posts.

Answer (score 5):

There's currently a transition going on with identification questions which are now off-topic as of December 15th. There were some spots missed including the tour and FAQ, but those are now updated and there are future plans that would have helped like the backlog of questions being closed which is planned for after the new year

I'm sorry you got caught up in this and I understand it's frustrating. This step is meant to improve the site as a whole and better provide more quality questions for the Music Fans SE.