# Should We Keep Old ID Questions

Tags: discussion, identification-questions

Given that ID questions make up the vast majority of our production, should we really be purging them out of the archives? I've personally put a lot of time and effort into those questions, and I'd hate to see that all just be deleted. That library of answered identifications is our main asset at this point.

Comment: @Namaskaram I agree that there may be some with broad enough appeal to keep for their historical value, though I'm not sure what the criteria would be.

Comment: @Namaskaram I confess, I find the score criterion unconvincing. But that said, restricting to question score >= 10 gives eight questions, which seems like a reasonable number to preserve. All eighth have at least one answer with a score of >= 2. I've not read the posts themselves to see if I agree they actually have historical value.

Comment: Another possible criterion is total views. For example, only eight posts have 20K or more views, and seven of those have accepted answers.

Comment: @Namaskaram FYI: I've made a chat post that may be of interest to you regarding a specific question to be preserved.

Comment: That library of answered ID questions is not an asset. A library is only useful if people can refer to it. With ID questions, once the poster has got their answer the question is of no use at all to other visitors. I've answered a lot of ID questions, and I'll be sorry to see them go, but it's the only way to put this site back on track.

Answer (score 4):

They're  not an asset, they're a burden. Most are low quality questions where only the OP can give us an answer and even the ones that have good sources like a link can rot and many have already. I also don't know besides finding new music that anyone besides the OP actually got useful information from them.

We can talk about a longer timescale for deletion, but at some point they should go as even having closed questions like that encourages more of them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest we use some version of Namaskaram's score-based criteria.

> For instance, the folks at Anime & Manga chose to first delete all ID posts except those posts with question score > 3 AND at least one answer with score > 2, and then they added the historical lock to all the ID posts

The scorched earth approach is extremely discouraging to me as MusicFans' most active poster.

Comment: The policy isn't targeted at you, but the content itself. Having the tag will cause those questions to appear as acceptable as has already been demonstrated since they were made off-topic and the tag was updated. Can you give one objective reason why we would keep something that's off-topic, little use to future users, and attracts other similar content? Yes you answered them, but that doesn't mean there's a difference between them being closed or deleted if they are off-topic and not of much use to future users.  You are proposing to keep them just because you answered them.

Comment: At this point, can we please take this to the main chatroom for the site? Responding to each of these posts is spreading the information thin. I think there's a better chance of actually understanding each other in chat where we can more directly discuss everything.

Comment: FYI: As @Dom suggests, I've posted in chat regarding a specific question I think should be preserved.

Answer (score -2):

[identify-this-genre](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-genre) should stay, and all deletions, closings and downvotes done by the mods should be reverted.

Someone could conceivably google, say "my uncle used to love me roger miller genre" and find them. So such questions are not only useful to those who asked them, but also others. And the purpose of this site is to serve both.

Furthermore, I'd like to point out that the justification for this policy, as it is being implemented, was **fraudulent**. The [proposed policy](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/731/proposal-limit-idenifcation-questions-to-tangible-questions-only-non-memory) was to to get rid of all "memory" questions:

> **Proposal: Limit Idenifcation questions to tangible questions only (non-memory)**
> ...
> A simple proposal drafted by the mods and community managers is to limit the ID questions to questions that have tangible sources including links, lyrics, pictures of sheet music or album covers ect.

But it's being applied to [questions like mine](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/11298/identify-this-genre-my-uncle-used-to-love-me-but-she-died-roger-miller) that included the title, singer and link, even showing the cover art.

[image]

It was not a moderator mistake either:

[image]

Comment: The answer to the proposal states support for banning __all__ id questions and was tied with the question until __after__ the dealine for the proposal. Regardless, you are saying we should keep a one sentence, off topic question which we made off-topic due to quality seems to be missing the whole point of all of this. I'd like you to participate in the site, but this is a bit extreme and triggered by moderators trying to moderate and clean up the site based on years of users not taking care of the site.