# Identification question closed post guidance should match close vote reason

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

When voting to close, the close reason reads

> Use this close reason for question asking for help identifying an **artist, song, genre, etc.** While these questions have been allowed in the past, they are currently off topic. More detail about why these questions are off topic can be found on meta. [emphasis mine]

But the guidance that appears with the closed post reads

> This question was closed because it is about identifying an **artist, song, or genre** of music, which is considered off topic It is not currently accepting answers. [emphasis mine]

The absence of "etc" in the closed post guidance can lead to confusion. The guidance should, at minimum, be changed to better match the close vote reason in that regard.

> This question was closed because it is about identifying an **artist, song, genre, etc.** of music, which is considered off topic It is not currently accepting answers. [emphasis mine]

Comment: Changed this to a discussion for now. While I agree with this change, we should make sure all the edits we need are discussed beforehand since only a CM can edit a current reason.

Comment: @Dom what precisely needs to be discussed here?

Comment: @Namaskaram the exact wording of the close reason. A CM is needed every time so let's try to get all the edits out now.

Comment: @Dom Is this only regarding the "needs improvement → A community specific reason → Identification question" close reason? There is one more community-specific close reason for questions that might be better suited to Music SE and another generic one called "Blatantly off-topic".

Comment: @Namaskaram this specific question yes. If you want to change the others (Blatantly off-topic is not really a close reason more of a place holder) it should be separate.

Comment: @Dom Okay. There are apparently five pieces of information that can be edited, is that right? I saw that this is so on SFF Meta for adding a new custom close reason: [New custom close reason: Future Works](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13445). Is that the same for our "Identification question" close reason? Because I don't know if it's already a "custom" one…

Comment: @Dom Any update?

Comment: @Namaskaram yes. All new close reasons have to be in that format.

Answer (score 2):

There are five pieces of text that need to be customized: two that appear in the close/flag dialog, and three that appear in the post notice after closure.

- The **brief description** is the part in bold in the flag/close dialog.
- The **usage guidance** is the explanatory text that follows the brief description.
- The **close description** is shown at the top of the close notice to everyone.
- The **post owner guidance** is visible only to the OP in the close notice.
- The **public guidance** is visible to everyone else in the close notice.

The brief description needs to be at least 10 characters long and at most 100 characters long; the others need to be at most 500 characters long.

---

Here is the generic information on each of the five pieces of text, along with sample text:

##### Close/Flag dialog

- ###### Brief description

  Briefly describe why the question is being closed

  > Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
- ###### Usage guidance

  Give the user guidance as to when they should select this option

  > While similar questions may be [on-topic] here, this question was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

##### Post notices

- ###### Close description

  When a post is closed with a single community-specific close reason, this message will be displayed publicly above any private guidance.

  > This question is [not reproducible or was caused by typos](/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.
- ###### Post owner guidance

  Provide meaningful actions a user can take to either get their question reopened or have a more favorable outcome in the future.

  > Update the question so others can reproduce the problem. You can [edit the question](edit) or [post a new question](ask).
- ###### Public guidance

  Explain why this question was closed and guide users to offer specific recommendations for how the asker might improve the question if appropriate.

  > Respond constructively to any followup questions by the post owner and reopen the question if it becomes reproducible.

---

Here are the currently used texts for the identification question close reason:

- ###### Brief description

  > Identification question
- ###### Usage guidance

  > Use this close reason for question asking for help identifying an artist, song, genre, etc. While these questions have been allowed in the past, they are currently off topic. More detail about why these questions are off topic can be found [on meta](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/the-identify-question-question-time-for-a-trial-separation).
- ###### Close description

  > This question was closed because it is about identifying an artist, song, or genre of music, which is considered off topic It is not currently accepting answers.
- ###### Post owner guidance

  > This question is an identification which is deemed out of scope for the site. You may still be able to get help in our informal [Music Fans Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) though. If this is not an identification question, please edit the question to make it clear using the button below. For more information about what types of questions are welcome here, please see the [Help center](/help).
- ###### Public guidance

  > Questions asking for music identification have been determined to be out of scope for the site as explained in [this meta discussion](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/715/the-identify-question-question-time-for-a-trial-separation). Questions like this may be asked in [Music Fans Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). If this is not an identification question, please help the user edit their question to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure what links are presently used in the post owner guidance. Someone else will have to confirm, or edit if needed. I guess suggestions for improvement can be taken under the comments here, or else made in a separate answer, whichever is convenient.